# Intent on NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

i am trying to implement a navigationDrawer for my app. After a lot of research, i found a way that works for me. It works with the example given in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do4vb0MdLFY&t=363s. In the video, they give the example with a Toast message. I am trying to create an intent instead. The problem is that i cannot do it like i am doing inside an Onclick function as they use a setNavigationItemSelectedListener. I cannot set up a val intent =when(view.id), this val i need it for making startActivity(intent) respond. In this code, no error appear but the intent inside startActivity isn't linked to a val but some weird library. I am trying to understand a way to turn around my code so it can make work my intent to link my activity. Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you so much for your help!

Here is my MainActivity.kt to make it clearer:

````
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.system.Os.close
import android.system.Os.open
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        drawerToggle.syncState()
        val navView= findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation_view)

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.nav_profile -> {
                  var intent=  Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
                }
              //  R.id.nav_profile -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            true
        }
        startActivity(intent)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
//    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
//        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
//        when (menuItem.itemId) {
//            R.id.nav_profile -> {
//               Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
//            }
//        }
//        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
//        return true
//    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Write startActivity(intent) below this line.

```
  R.id.nav_profile -> {
                  var intent=  Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
                   startActivity(intent)
                }
```